# Apache Cordova: SQL windows authentication over VPN

Tags: sql, apache, cordova, vpn

I am super new to the Hybrid architecture of Cordova Dev Tool and not very familiar with the architecture and the capabilities of it. I am working on building an app using Cordova that will allow only my company users (internal) to login and access it. Our users use the Cisco anyconnect VPN mobile client on mobile devices. I would like to authenticate that the user is connected to VPN when they login to my app. If VPN is not enabled, the app should error out with some sort of a message. Any ideas or sample code would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a resource that they can only access when using the VPN? I'd suggest that in your app you make a HTTP request to access that resource, if they're using the VPN it'll work but otherwise it won't work.

Comment: by resource, you mean, could that be an internally hosted web service?